# Xamarin.forms Hybridwebview Navigating and Navigate Problem

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i need help. Navigating and navigate codes do not work in my project. animation is not deleted when the page is full. External link not working in device browser. My Code:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        webViewElement.Source = "https://mywebsite.com/";
        webViewElement.RegisterAction(ExecuteActionFromJavascript);
        _deviceFeaturesHelper = new DeviceFeaturesHelper();
    }

    void WebOnNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs args)
    {
        loading.IsVisible = true;

        if (args.Url.StartsWith("https://mywebsite.com/"))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
             Device.OpenUri(new Uri(args.Url));

            args.Cancel = true;
        }         
    }

    void WebOnNavigated(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs s)
    {
        loading.IsVisible = false;
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        webViewElement.GoBack();
        return true;
    }
```

Yes, navigate event not trigger. yes i tested the app on my android device. sorry for my english.. My xaml:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>


    <AbsoluteLayout>

        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
            <controls:HybridWebView
            x:Name="webViewElement"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Navigating="WebOnNavigating"
            Navigated="WebOnNavigated"/>
        </StackLayout>
       

        <Frame AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,AutoSize,AutoSize"
               x:Name="loading"
               BackgroundColor="Gray"
               Opacity="0.9"
               IsVisible="True">
            <StackLayout>
                <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True"/>
                <Label Text="Loading..." TextColor="White"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
        
  
    
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: "do not work" is not a useful description of the problem.  What specifically does that mean?  What debugging steps have you taken to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Does `do not work` mean navigate event not trigger ? Do you assign the event in xaml or not ? Did you test on android simulator or real device ? What's the version of `xamarin.forms` on your side ?

Comment: Yes, navigate event not trigger. yes i tested the app on my android device. sorry for my english..

Comment: My xaml:  <controls:HybridWebView
                x:Name="webViewElement"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Navigating="WebOnNavigating"
                Navigated="WebOnNavigated"/>

Comment: Please provide the code of class `HybridWebView ` and relevant custom renderer code so that we can test it .

Comment: A more descriptive version of the question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68648978/xamarin-forms-shouldoverrideurlloading-trigger

Comment: A more descriptive version of the question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68648978/xamarin-forms-shouldoverrideurlloading-trigger

Answer (score 0):

Navigation event would not be triggered because you're using a custom renderer for the webview and reset the WebViewClient, we can manage the navigation event inside custom the class .

Since `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` method is obsolete , I strongly recommend you to use  another method like `OnPageStarted` , `OnPageFinished` ,`OnReceivedError` .

Show the activityindicator in `OnPageStarted`  method , and hide it in `OnPageFinished` and `OnReceivedError` method .

To achieve it we can use DependencyService , but Messaging Center is better here .

#### JavascriptWebViewClient

```
public override void OnPageStarted(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url, Bitmap favicon)
{
    base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    MessagingCenter.Send<object, bool>(this, "Hi", true);
}

public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
{
    base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
    view.EvaluateJavascript(_javascript, null);

    MessagingCenter.Send<object,bool>(this, "Hi",false);
}

public override void OnReceivedError(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error)
{
     base.OnReceivedError(view, request, error);
     MessagingCenter.Send<object, bool>(this, "Hi", false);
}
```

#### MainPage

```
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, bool>(this,"Hi",(obj,show)=> {
     loading.IsVisible = show;
     loading.IsRunning = show;
 });
```