# Any method in xamarin forms equivalent to ShouldOverrideUrlLoading method of android?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Any method in xamarin forms equivalent to shouldoverride method of android?

I am looking for a method that I can call when a button is clicked on webview. this is the android sample code that is working.

```
        webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        webView.SetWebViewClient(new HybridWebViewClient(this));
        webView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
```

on HybridWebViewClient class

```
public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
{
}
```

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Xamarin.Forms is a platform that integrates Android and iOS and Windows. For platform-specific features, you can use Custom renderer to call code on Android platform.

   For details you can refer to: [What is Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin-forms) and [Custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview).
2. Using the OnPageStarted method, the OnPageFinished method, and the OnReceivedError method is also a good choice.

   Details can be found in the answer at this link：[Xamarin.Forms ShouldOverrideUrlLoading Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68648978/xamarin-forms-shouldoverrideurlloading-trigger)